# Import image from local network in php

Tags: php, html, image

I have a script that fetches some pictures in `php` and display them on my website. The thing is when I out of my local network and access the site, the images won't display, cause it have the local url. Is there a way to import them temporary?. So, I will be able to see it outside the local network? Without the need of giving public access of the image link.

Here a sample of the code:

```
foreach($sbJSON->{data}->{soon} as $show) {
     $newepisode = "S" . $show->{//.≥≥season} . "E" . $show->{episode};
     $text = $show->{show_name} . " " . $newepisode . ": " . $show->{airdate};
     $newfeedimage = $feedimage .  $show->{tvdbid};
     echo "<h1>$text</h1>";   
     echo "<br>"; 
     echo '<img src="'.$newfeedimage.'"/>';
}
```

And here the image url of my local network:

```
 $feedimage = "http://".$ip."/api/".$api."/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid=";
```

Comment: What are you really asking here? `import them temporarily`? Import them temporarily *where*?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a PHP proxy.  Beware of security issues.

Comment: Yes the thing is that the picture is on another computer in my network, so when i browse locally my website, it access the image without any problem, but when accessing from outside the network, for sure the link is not available (19.168.2..) and i don't want to forward this computer in public so i was thinking to fetch the picture on my local computer temporally to my hosting directory to access them outside the network.